# Obtain entire array from a single cell that is part of a collection of cells containing the same array formula?

Tags: excel, vba

It's probably best if I explain this with an example...

Say we have in a worksheet cells `A1:C1` containing the values `[1,2,3]`.

I want to take the square of each of these numbers but I do this using a cell-formula so in cell `A2` I have `{=A1:C1^2}`. This is an array-formula. However, if I only press `ctrl+alt+enter` in cell `A2`, I see the first element of the array squared `(i.e. A1^2 = 1^2 = 1)`.

If I select all of `A2:C2` hit `ctrl+alt+enter` it expands out the entire array-formula across the three cells and we see the result of `[1,4,9]`.

What I want is to only have to place the array formula in cell `A2` and write VBA to be able to access the entire array for the entire operation (i.e. `A1:C1^2`).

I don't want to execute the function again in VBA as the array must already be stored in memory when we execute `{=A1:C1^2}` in cell `A2` so how can I get the entire array result from a single cell that is part of a larger array?

Note: this is just an example, I plan to do this for large, unknown sized arrays.

Comment: So you want to store the entire array in a single cell and then be able to access it? That isn't how array formulas work. In your example -- only the value 1 is actually stored in `A2` (`=SUM(A2)` returns 1, not 14 -- even if you enter the sum as an array formula). You can combine the values into a string with some delimiter and then use VBA to split the string and extract the values, though that will seldom be more efficient than just computing the values on the fly.

Comment: Are you saying you want VBA to autofill your formula across or down for the whole "array"? That is, you want to start typing a formula into A2, then select A1:C1, then type your operation resulting in "=A1:C1^2"; then hit ctrl-shift-enter to make it an array formula; then you want VBA to automatically autofill into B2 and C2?

Comment: I thought that {=(A1:C1)^2} would return an array, Excel then knows this is an array and depending on how large the selected area is, outputs the elements of the resulting array. Essentially, it's a more fundamental question I'm asking - when you tell Excel to execute a cell formula, does it compute the entire formula and then determine how many elements are to be printed out based off the area the user has provided? Or, does it just compute element by element of the array based on the area selected?

Comment: @as9422 Good question. Since arrays are typically computed in a loop anyway I would suspect that Excel only computes as much of the array as is needed. Anything else would be inefficient.

Comment: @JohnColeman I thought so - kind of frustrating to hear but I had half expected that it wouldn't be possible to perform exactly what I was asking for. Thanks for you help though!

Edit: although - do you know if it's possible to tell VBA to not execute functions that are being called by others in the same workbook? That could be a workaround for my problem (this all sprouts off the fact that I don't want to execute the same function twice on refresh).

Answer (score 0):

Excel cells can only contain scalar values, so what you want to do is not possible without using EVALUATE in your VBA to execute the formula from A2.

And you need to be careful how you use EVALUATE: it has many peculiar quirks.

(see my [blog post on EVALUATE](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/) )

Comment: Does Excel only then calculate the portion of the array formula that is covered by the selected area then?

Comment: No, AFAIK Excel calculates all the values so that if you wrap the formula in an aggregation function like SUM it can aggregate all the values. But a single cell only has a single place to hold a value that other formulas can read. So the part of Excel that stores the results of formulas throws any other values away.

Answer (score 0):

Excel computes the entire array and displays what it can. This is based on what cells the user selects prior to the array confirmation.

Charles is correct in his answer. There is no way to get at the array without recalculating it with Evaluate(), like so:

```
MsgBox Join(Evaluate([a2].Formula))
```

VBA does have the `HasArray` property for the range object, and in your example with [a2] being the sole cell in the array formula, the `HasArray` property will return True.

Unfortunately, there is no corresponding `GetArray` property, which is exactly what you are after.

My take is that Excel's worksheet calculation engine does indeed maintain the array in memory, but this is a separate construct form the range and cells and VBA has no access to it.

Comment: I'm not sure that Excel computes the entire array. I completely filled columns A:J using `=rand()` and pasted them in place as values. Then in K1 I put the formula `{=EXP(SIN(COS(SQRT(ABS(TAN(A:J))))))}`. Computing the entire array would involve over 60 million function calls (-- but the value in K1 is calculated in a fraction of a second

Comment: I'm sure there are optimizations that Excel makes. Your's is an edge case... one cell output for entire columns. Does it take longer when you enlarge the confirmation range to two cells, for example, [K2:K2] ?

Comment: I don't know -- I deleted that workbook and lunch break is almost over. Given the closed-source nature of Excel it is all somewhat speculative. OP's question involved exactly this "edge case".

Comment: Sort of. The one cell output yes. The multiple full-column reference no. Since you could not test it, I can attest that it is vastly slower. In many scenarios the calc engine could make tremendous gains in efficiency if it maintained the array. My experience leads me to 'guess' that most of the time it does, unless it considers it too expensive.

Comment: I don't know -- I just repeated the experiment and filled all 100 cells in the range K1:T10 with the formula `{=EXP(SIN(COS(SQRT(ABS(TAN(A1:J1048575^2))))))}` (which stops 1 row short of being whole columns and threw in a square just for good measure) and those 100 cells are filled up in less than a second though computing the full array would require billions of floating point operations. Interestingly, trying to evaluate `{=MAX(EXP(SIN(COS(SQRT(ABS(TAN(A1:J1048575^2)))))))}` as an array formula in K1 gives me an "Excel ran out of resources" error message.